# Setting mongoose geospatial index range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to implement a tilemap using mongodb geospatial indexes.
I run a server script which includes the following piece of code:

```
var TileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    location: [Number],
    tile_type: Number
});

TileSchema.index({location: '2d'}, {min: 500, max: 500});
```

But no matter what value I set for 'min' and 'max' properties it still throws error when I try to save a Tile  which is e.g. out of 180 longitude. Is this even the correct way to set these properties in mongoose?

The following does not throw any error.

```
Tile.on('index', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err); // error occurred during index creation
})
```

A debug log where I tried to assign *max* and *min* to 500 and -500:

```
Listening on port 1337...
Mongoose: tiles.ensureIndex({ location: '2d' }) { safe: undefined, background: true, max: 500, min: -500 }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -48, -48 ], [ 48, 48 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -48, -48 ], [ 48, 48 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -64, -48 ], [ 32, 32 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -112, -48 ], [ -32, 32 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -176, -48 ], [ -96, 32 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -240, -64 ], [ -160, 32 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -272, -64 ], [ -192, 16 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
{ [MongoError: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: -186.0, 1: -24.0 }] name: 'MongoError' }
Mongoose: tiles.insert({ __v: 0, _id: ObjectId("54034534c480de3512a82523"), tile_type: 100, location: [ -219, -27 ] }) {}  
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _id: ObjectId('54034534c480de3512a82523'), location: [ -219, -27 ], tile_type: 100, __v: 0 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16755,
  err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can\'t extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _id: ObjectId(\'54034534c480de3512a82523\'), location: [ -219, -27 ], tile_type: 100, __v: 0 }' }
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -288, -64 ], [ -208, 16 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
{ [MongoError: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: -194.0, 1: -24.0 }] name: 'MongoError' }
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -272, -64 ], [ -192, 16 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
{ [MongoError: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: -186.0, 1: -24.0 }] name: 'MongoError' }
Mongoose: tiles.find({ location: { '$geoWithin': { '$box': [ [ -272, -64 ], [ -192, 16 ] ] } } }) { fields: undefined }  
{ [MongoError: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: -186.0, 1: -24.0 }] name: 'MongoError' }
```

The *find* queries in the beginning can be ignored I guess, they are just effect of my scrolling on the map in the game client.

Comment: I don't fully understand. What are you setting min and max to and why? Show us an insert that causes an error and what the error is. Turn on mongoose debugging and show us what it says for the indexing operation and the insert.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it's more clear now. I am trying to set the min and max because I want to achieve something similiar to this http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/35215504793/the-wonderful-world-of-geospatial-indexes-in-mongodb

Comment: Works fine for me when I test adding a 2d index, inserting the doc that errored out due to malformed geometry, and then finding with the given geo queries. Try testing this out in a toy collection in the mongo shell and see if it works for you. What version of MongoDB is this? What other indices, if any, are on the tiles collection?

Comment: It worked actually. I just forgot to delete the indexes when I re-run the app and where stacking them on top of each other..

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by me accidentally recreating the indices everytime I run the app, because I didn't realize I have to delete them everytime before I do this.